# DbSet, DbContext, EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am new to ASP.NET and very new to EF. I am trying to develop an application and after reading some sites I've decided I'm going to create a 3-tier application (DAL, BL, a website as the frontend).

For the DAL layer I've taken inspiration from here
http://codefizzle.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/correct-use-of-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-asp-net-mvc/

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    void Add(T a);
}

public interface IUnitOfWork:IDisposable
{
    IGenericRepository<UserInfo> UserInfoRepository { get; }
    void Commit();
}

public class EfGenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private  DbSet<T> _dbSet;
    public EfGenericRepository(DbSet<T> dbSet)
    {
        _dbSet = dbSet;
    }

    public void Add(T a)
    {
       _dbSet.Add(a);          
    }   
}
public class EfUnitOfWork : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{      
    private readonly EfGenericRepository<UserInfo> _userInfoRepo;
    public DbSet<UserInfo> UserInfos { get; set; }

    public EfUnitOfWork()
    {
        _userInfoRepo = new EfGenericRepository<UserInfo>(UserInfos);
    }


    public IGenericRepository<UserInfo> UserInfoRepository
    {
        get { return _userInfoRepo; }
    }
    public void Commit()
    {
        this.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

and my BL looks like this:

```
public interface IBussinessLogic
{
   void AddUserInfo(string c);
}
public class BusinessLogic: IBussinessLogic
{
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public BusinessLogic()
    {
        _unitOfWork = new EfUnitOfWork();
    }

    public void AddUserInfo(string c)
    {
        _unitOfWork.UserInfoRepository.Add(new UserInfo()
        {
            Address = c
        });
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }
}
```

Now I am using web-forms but I don't think that should be an issue.
On click i execute this:

```
IBussinessLogic businessLogic = new BusinessLogic();    
businessLogic.AddUserInfo(address.Text);
```

But nothing happens,my data is not saved in the db.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: The code looks fine and like it should work. Are you sure that your connection string is pointing to where you are looking for the data?

Comment: My connection string is ok.Weird!! I've tried this: using (AEntity ae = new AEntity()){
            ae.UserInfo.Add(new UserInfo(){Address=address.Text});
       AEntity.SaveChanges();
} and it works